# ASP.NET MVC 4 - Partial views and Ajax.Actionlink

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I am trying to put on my homepage some link that render partial views - I want to display some info from the database when users click a link: the link should be replaced by text on the same page. I followed a tutorial but I cannot get it to work in my project. Here is what I have:

My Home/Index view:

```
<div id="NeZaman">
@Ajax.ActionLink("Ne Zaman Gelcekmiş?", "NeZaman", new AjaxOptions {
                                        UpdateTargetId="NeZaman",
                                        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                        HttpMethod="GET" })
</div>
```

My HomeController:

```
    private CaglaContext db = new CaglaContext();

    public PartialViewResult NeZaman()
    {
        var neZaman = db.Caglas.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Select(c => c.NeZamanGelcek).FirstOrDefault();
        return PartialView("_NeZaman", neZaman);
    }
```

My partial view (_NeZaman.cshtml):

```
    @model caglageldimi.Models.Cagla

<p>
   @Model.NeZamanGelcek
</p>
```

My Model(Cagla.cs):

```
public class Cagla
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool GeldiMi { get; set; }
    public string NeZamanGelcek { get; set; }
    public string Nerdeymis { get; set; }
}
```

So I'm passing in a neZaman value that the partial view is supposed to use, but how?

Comment: Atm I'm getting this error: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.String', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'caglageldimi.Models.Cagla'. No idea how to fix that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've set your patial view's model to your class:

> caglageldimi.Models.Cagla

But you're passing a string:

> db.Caglas.Where(c => c.Id == 1).Select(c => c.NeZamanGelcek).FirstOrDefault();

Your select statement is only grabbing the "NeZamanGelcek" string property value to send to your partial view.

Changing your partial view's model to System.String should fix it:

> @model System.String